# non-blocking y-or-n-p

Tags: key-bindings

I have a function that offers to do handy things. Right now, it's using `y-or-n-p` to ask if it should take action. The problem is that `y-or-n-p` blocks the command loop, which is inconvenient if you want to pass on the action. Instead, I'd like `y` to execute the action, but let everything else through.

```el
(defun my/y-or-n-p (prompt callback)
  (message prompt)
  (set-transient-map `(keymap (121 . ,callback))))

(defun test-my/y-or-n-p ()
  (my/y-or-n-p "message?" (lambda () (interactive) (message "message hi!"))))

;; this works
(test-my/y-or-n-p)

;; this does not
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'test-my/y-or-n-p)
```

There are two problems with my code:

- The prompt in the echo area can be overwritten by other messages
- Doesn't seem to work in `emacs-startup-hook` (and maybe other hooks)

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: I just tried your example and it worked for me in the `emacs-startup-hook`

Comment: @IqbalAnsari but only if it's the last item on the hook.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like the following should work

```el
(defun my-lenient-y-or-n-p (prompt)
  (let ((query-replace-map (copy-keymap query-replace-map)))
    (define-key query-replace-map [t] 'skip)
    (y-or-n-p prompt)))
```

If you look at the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Yes_002dor_002dNo-Queries.html) of `y-or-n-p`, it mentions that it looks up the `query-replace-map` to decide which action to take for a given key. I am quoting it here for completeness (emphasis mine)

> (...)
>
> To be precise, **this function translates user input into responses by
>   consulting the bindings in `query-replace-map`**; see the documentation
>   of that variable for more information.  In this case, the useful
>   bindings are `act`, `skip`, `recenter`, `scroll-up`, `scroll-down`,
>   and `quit`. An `act` response means yes, and **a `skip` response means
>   no**. A `quit` response means to invoke `keyboard-quit`. If the user
>   enters `recenter`, `scroll-up`, or `scroll-down` responses, perform
>   the requested window recentering or scrolling and ask again.
>
> (...)

So basically if we can invoke `y-or-n-p` with modified `query-replace-map` which defines the binding `skip` as the default we should get what you want.

We can achieve this by copying the `query-replace-map` (so that global value is unchanged) and defining the binding `skip` for all undefined keys. So how do we define a default binding in a keymap, for this see the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html) of `define-keymap` (emphasis mine)

> (...) KEY is a string or a vector of symbols and characters, representing a
>   sequence of keystrokes and events.  Non-ASCII characters with codes
>   above 127 (such as ISO Latin-1) can be represented by vectors. Two
>   types of vector have special meanings:  [remap COMMAND] remaps any key
>   binding for COMMAND.  **[t] creates a default definition**, which applies
>   to any event with no other definition in KEYMAP.

So binding `[t]` to `skip` in the copy of `query-replace-map` should do the trick for us. Of course we let bind the new keymap around the call to `y-or-no-p` so that the modified keymap is used instead of the global definition

Comment: Good explanation, including mentioning `[t]`.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly and is a lot less hacky than what I had in mind.

Comment: Found this a useful addition to the above: 
`(define-key query-replace-map (kbd "RET") 'skip)`

Comment: This still blocks the command loop no?